# Perfect matching for graph with two edges for every node

Tags: combinatorics

Consider two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, each of size $n$. Some (undirected) edges connect nodes in $A$ with nodes in $B$. Suppose that each node (in $A$ or $B$) is adjacent to at least two edges. Is it true that there must be a perfect matching between $A$ and $B$?

I think this is related to Hall's marriage theorem somehow, but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counterexample:** Suppose $n=5$, $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\}$, $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5\}$. Draw $6$ edges joining $a_1,a_2,a_3$ to $b_1,b_2$, and draw $6$ more edges joining $a_4,a_5$ to $b_3,b_4,b_5$.

You get a correct statement if you change "at least two" to "exactly two" (or "exactly $k$" for any natural $k$).

Comment: It does not become true by changing "at least two" to "exactly two".  Consider a hexagon (6-cycle), with three consecutive nodes as set $A$ and the other three as $B$.  Each node in $A \cup B$ has two edges (2-regularity), but there is no perfect matching from $A$ to $B$ (there are only two edges between these sets; a perfect matching would require at least 3).

Comment: I think there's an unstated assumption that the graph is bipartite and $A$, $B$ are the vertex classes.

Comment: @BenMillwood Yep. I wasn't even aware it was unstated. On reading "some edges connect nodes in $A$ with nodes in $B$" I unconsciously supplied "and there are no other edges".

Comment: @BenMillwood: Sure, it's true if the graph is bipartite with parts $A$ and $B$.  But the OP conspicuously says it's unclear "how to apply" Hall's marriage theorem.  The bipartite assumption is also missing from the follow-up Question posted by the same user, as a result of what bof said here.