# Perfect matching for graph with exactly $k$ edges for every node

Tags: combinatorics

Consider two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, each of size $n$. Some (undirected) edges connect nodes in $A$ with nodes in $B$. Suppose that each node (in $A$ or $B$) is adjacent to **exactly** $k$ of those edges, for some fixed $k\geq 1$. Is it true that there must be a perfect matching between $A$ and $B$?

(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860456/perfect-matching-for-graph-with-two-edges-for-every-node/860485#860485) for related statement.)

Comment: There is no guarantee that there would be as many as $n$ edges connecting set $A$ to set $B$, so this cannot be true ("there must be a perfect matching between $A$ and $B$"), despite what the Answer on your previous Question told you.

Comment: Hall's marriage tells you there is a saturating mathcing of $A$, but since |A|=|B| this must mean this is a perfect mathcing.

Comment: This is the second Question (see "related" statement linked above) where the user omits any claim that the graph is bipartite.  Without the bipartite assumption conveniently supplied by the "answers", the conclusion is not true.

Comment: And posted again with a difference of 4 hours: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860797/all-k-regular-subgraphs-of-k-n-n-have-a-perfect-matching-a-proof-without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Use [Hall's marriage theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem). Choose any set $\displaystyle\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_m\}$ vertices from $A$ and consider set of adjacent edges to $\displaystyle\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_m\}$ . There are exactly $m \cdot k$ edges. So they must be adjacent to at least $m$ vertex from $B$, because each vertices from be is adjacent to at most (exactly) $k$ vertices ([Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)).

Answer (score 1):

We appeal to [Hall's marriage theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation) which says there is a perfect matching in a bipartite graph with bipartite sets $X$ and $Y$ of equal size if and only if $|W|\le |N(W)|$ for every $W\subseteq X$, where $N(W)$ denotes the set of vertices which are adjacent to some element in $W$.

Let $S\subseteq X$. Now consider $Y\backslash N(S)$. Every vertex in $Y\backslash N(S)$ has degree $k$ and by definition none of the edges connect an element of $S$. Hence all edges must connect to some vertex in $X\backslash S$. Hence the number of edges adjacent to vertices in $X\backslash S$ must be greater than or equal to the number of edges adjacent to vertices in $Y\backslash N(S)$.

This gives us
$$\begin{align}
k|X\backslash S|&\ge k|Y\backslash N(S)|
\\\implies |X\backslash S|&\ge |Y\backslash N(S)|
\\\implies n-|S|&\ge n-|N(S)|
\\\implies |N(S)|&\ge|S|
\end{align}
$$

So by Hall's marriage theorem there exists a perfect matching.